# Gapps returns undefined for getParents()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm running an Add-on for spreadsheets where users can create a document.
This document will be places inside a folder of the current year at the location of the spreadsheet.
This has worked some time but for some reason (I can't find why, or I'm searching in the wrong places) it stopped working.

To find the folder I use this code:

```
const ss = sa.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var documentID = ss.getId();
var DriveID = DriveApp.getFileById(documentID);
var parents = DriveID.getParents();
console.log(parents.hasNext());
var parent;
  
while(parents.hasNext()){
  parent = parents.next();
  console.log(`next parent = ${parent.getName()}`);
}
```

When I run this part on my own account the *parents.hasNext()* returns true and I've got a name in the While loop.

But when I run the same script on a test account i get false en that's it, no while loop.
First thing I thought that it was the issue with sharing within drive, but it's set that Everyone of my company has access (read/write) to that folder, subfolder and folder above, so I am kinda running out of ideas what this might be.

Who can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause I can think is that your test account doesn't have access to the folder this file is in. Because of that, your script cannot get it. Sharing the entire folder should solve the issue (remember that it may take a while to fully propagate after sharing).

Comment: I have the entire folder shared, even the folder above. I've let like 48 Hours pass when testing again, I've just set it that Everyone in the company can find and edit it, still no success.

Comment: With the other account, try using [File: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) were the `fileId` is the ID of the folder where the spreadsheet is in. Doing that will check the permissions.

Comment: Tested it with Own and test account, when I run this, both accounts get a (green) 200.

Comment: With the id of the folder (not the file)? If so, do the same with the file and make sure to include the field `parents`, and see if there is a difference in the result.

Comment: When I'm adding `parents` : own account I've got green 200 with 1 ID, when I'm doing it with the test account, I'll get a Green 200 with an empty `{}`. When I'm doing the same with a Subfolder in that folder (that is using the Share option from the folder with the problem) I get (on the test account) Green 200 with 1 ID.

Comment: Could you try running the `File: get` from the Apps Script project with the test account? It should list the parents. Code: ```function test() {console.log(/*DriveApp.getFileById()*/UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()}?fields=parents`,{headers:{'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}}).getContentText())}```

Comment: I've copied the exact code from above, the logging on both my own and the test account give an array with 1 parent.

Comment: With the test account, what happens if you try calling `DriveApp.getFolderById('parent_ID')`?

Comment: I wasn't able to test this one out, but I've asked a few collegue's to try the "test function" out and they came up with empty arrays. I haven't changed the rights to the folder (shared with everyone in the company) although my own test account seems to get a result from the test function.

Comment: Is this file in a shared drive?

Comment: The folder is located in "My drive", not a Team Drive/Shared Drive. I've set the entire folder to: `*Company* everyone with the link can edit`.

Comment: Could you try adding `DriveID.addEditor(Session.getActiveUser())` before calling `DriveID.getParents()`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my "test subject" for the code decided to go on holiday so I had to find someone else. I've added the code in a new function so i could see the difference. Unfortunatly when adding the add Editor, I still get an false on `parents.hasNext()` and the while loop won't work because of the false.

Comment: @Maurice I can't reproduce exactly the same behavior. Do you have a Workspace account? If so, I'd ask your domain administrator to [contact Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213). As far as I know, they can look into your specific case.